# Using AQuery library with PUT request and StringEntity(String)

Tags: android, http, request

I use AndroidQuery(AQuery) library for Android and I need to create PUT request with StringEntity(some string) entity.

My code, what is wrong? Your suggestions? I tried use without" .header("_method", "PUT")  "

```
HttpEntity entity = null;
    try {
        entity = new StringEntity(stringData, HTTP.UTF_8);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put(AQuery.POST_ENTITY, entity);

    AQuery aq = new AQuery(this);
    aq.progress(pDialog).ajax(url, params, String.class, new AjaxCallback<String>() {

        @Override
        public void callback(String url, String json, AjaxStatus status) {
            if(status.getCode() == 200) {

            } else {

            }

        }
    }.header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded") 
    .header("_method", "PUT"));
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a bit hidden, but AjaxCallback has a private `method` field (and corresponding setter) used for determining the HTTP method to use. By default, it uses `METHOD_DETECT`, which tries to figure out what to use, and when you add parameters, it will think it's a POST.

So, instead of:

```
.header("_method", "PUT"));
```

Use

```
.method(AQuery.METHOD_PUT)
```

(Ref: https://github.com/androidquery/androidquery/blob/master/src/com/androidquery/callback/AbstractAjaxCallback.java#L280)

Answer (score -4):

AndroidQuery doesn't support PUT and DELETE requests in general. :( Sad.

Comment: Looks like it is supported based on the approved answer